# Centering the called blocks relative to the parent block JS

Tags: javascript, css

There is a block that, when you click on +, calls up the same block on the side of it. The blocks are connected by a line, when pressed again, another block is called. Below is the diagram and my code. Question: how to make the new blocks (green blocks in the picture) are centered relative to the parent (red blocks in the picture), regardless of the placement of the parent block, as in the diagram?

[image]

```js
let distance = 250;
let count = 0;

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
        let div = document.createElement("div"),
            father = e.path[5];
            count = count + 100;
        div.classList = father.classList;
        div.style.left = father.offsetLeft + distance + "px";
        div.style.top = father.offsetTop + count + "px";

        let arrow_width = distance - father.offsetWidth;
        div.innerHTML =
            father.innerHTML +
            `<div class='arrow' style='left: ${-arrow_width}px;width:${arrow_width}px;'><div></div></div>`;
        document.body.append(div);
    }
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

article,
aside,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f5f7fa;
}

html,
body {
  scrollbar-color: red #1a1a1a;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

body .card {
  position: relative;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem -1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
}

body .card .multi-button {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 0rem;
  height: 0rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0, 1);
}

body .card .multi-button button {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0rem -0.25rem var(--background);
}

body .card .multi-button button:hover {
  background: var(--text);
  color: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem -0.25rem var(--background);
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(1) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 37.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 37.5%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 15.625%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ *:nth-child(3) {
  left: 15.625%;
  top: 50%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(1),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(1) {
  left: 62.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(2),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(2) {
  left: 37.5%;
  top: 18.75%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(3),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(3) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 37.5%;
}

body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(4),
body .card .multi-button button:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *:nth-child(4) {
  left: 18.75%;
  top: 62.5%;
}

body .card .cardcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: var(--background);
  color: var(--text);
}

body .card:hover .multi-button,
body .card .multi-button:focus-within {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px #f3faf7;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:decrement {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment {
  background-color: #000;
}

.invisible {
  display: none !important;
}

.schema {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.optionsmenu {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

.optionsmenu textarea {
  color: #000;
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-10 {
  position: absolute;
}

.col-1-2,
.col-2-3,
.col-3-4,
.col-4-5,
.col-5-6,
.col-6-7,
.col-7-8,
.col-8-9,
.col-9-10 {
  position: absolute;
}

.schema2 {
  display: none;
}

.blue {
  --background: #3f72c3;
  --text: white;
}

.purple {
  --background: #743da0;
  --text: white;
}

.white {
  --background: #e3e8e6;
  --text: black;
}

.arguments {
  z-index: 9999999999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 2;
}

#in-kod {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

.add {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
}

.btn {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.btn2 {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
.btn3 {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.in-kod {
  display: block;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-6' style="top:50px;left:50px;">
    <span class="in-kod">
        <div class="card purple">
            <div class="multi-button">
                <span class="add">
                    <button class="btn">+</button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="cardcontainer">
                <textarea class="arguments"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution that uses CSS Grid.

I put the parent and the children into separate containers and wrap both of them in a grid. Then center align the grid items. This ensures no matter how many items you have in the children block, it's always center aligned with the parent.

Give the following a shot. Click on any Child to add another child and see for yourself.

NOTE: jQuery is only used to make it interactive. The actual CSS solution doesn't require any JS.

```js
const children = $(".child");
children.on("click", () => {
  $(".children").append("<div class='child'>Child</div>");
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}
.parent, .child {
  min-height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  color: white;
}
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.child + .child {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    Parent
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```